# How to print the ASCII value of characters in a string as binary numbers?

Tags: arrays, ruby, binary, ascii, each

I am trying achieve it by different methods but still it give a error so how to use **.ord** to achieve it or there is any other way to achieve it ? 
Basically I want get ASCII value of every character in the string then converting each of them in to binary by using `.to_s(2)`
 Here is my code ↓

```
input = gets.chomp.split("").each { |s| s.ord.to_i }
puts input.to_s(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
gets.chomp.chars.each { |ch| puts ch.ord }
```

`chars` method is another way to do `split("")`

Comment: Can you give a code so its output is like a = 1100001 b = 1100010 ....
Here is finally code ↓
input = gets.chomp.chars.each { |ch| puts  ch.ord.to_s(2) }

Comment: sure. `input = gets.chomp.chars.each { |ch| puts "#{ch}= #{ch.ord.to_s(2)}" } `

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each_codepoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-each_codepoint) to iterate the string's codepoints and [`printf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) with `%b` to format it as a binary number.

```
'foo bar'.each_codepoint { |c| printf("%07b\n", c) }
```

Output:

```
1100110
1101111
1101111
0100000
1100010
1100001
1110010
```

The `07` prefix sets the *minimum* width to 7 and pads missing bits with `0` (see [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for formatting options). There might be characters with more than 7 bits, though.